# Как мне поместить содержимое одного div выше соседнего?

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка

[image: прим]
У меня есть 2 div-а. Первый и второй столбцы, как показано на рисунке,
В первом столбце есть кнопка, которая показывает третий Div: всплывающее окно.
В первом столбце, в коде есть overflow-y: auto
Оно есть, потому что первому столбцу нужна вертикальный скролл(много информации)
Если его удалить, то и скролла не будет
Я попытался решить проблему следующим образом

**Первая колонка**

```
height: calc(100vh - 80px);
padding: 20px 5px;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
overflow-y: auto;
```

**Вторая колонка**

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 10px;
padding: 17px 0 20px 0;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
overflow-y: auto;
```

**Pop-up**

```
position: absolute;
top: -5px;
left: calc(100% + 5px);
z-index: 999;
```

Comment: Привет! Добавьте [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Код слишком большой чтобы тут выкладывать, мне нужно положить поп-ап выше второй колонки

Comment: А попап точно уходит под правую колонку, а не обрезается из-за `overflow` как и должно быть при этом? Удалите правую колонку, там будет попап под ней?

Comment: @PavelGrishaev да, если вторую удалить под не будет попап

Comment: `Код слишком большой` — потому и требуется **миниальный**: [mcve]